# How to upload more than 2048 bytes of data to a FTP file using the SIMCOM A7672E AT+CFTPSPUT command?

Tags: ftp, upload, at-command

SIMCOM A7672E AT+CFTPSPUT command fails after initial data burst

I need to upload more than 2048bytes of text data to a file on an FTP server. I can successfully append data to an existing file be setting the  argument to the length of the file. However after the AT+CFTPSPUT command has executed once, subsequent commands fails.

I've tests AT+CFTPSSIZE and another AT+CFTPSPUT, both timeout or return an error.

I can however successfully logout and stop the ftp service.

How can I upload more than 2048 bytes of data to a ftp file without having to logout after each chunk of data

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, it's a bug in the firmware on the A7672E modules. It has been fixed, version B05 and above resolves this problem.
The change notes indicates 2 bugs that might have affected y situation.

1. The port is disabled when using CFTPSPUT while connected on a 2G network
2. FTP uploads fails when the filesize change.